# count number of directors which have more than 15 movies

Tags: mysql

I need help with a mySQL query.

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `actor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(35) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `actor_name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `casting` (
  `movieid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `actorid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ord` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`movieid`,`actorid`),
  KEY `casting_movie` (`movieid`),
  KEY `casting_actor` (`actorid`),
  KEY `casting_ord` (`ord`)
);

CREATE TABLE `movie` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `title` varchar(70) default NULL,
  `yr` decimal(4,0) default NULL,
  `score` float default NULL,
  `votes` int(11) default NULL,
  `director` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `movie_title` (`title`)
);
```

I need to select the count of the number of directors which have more than 15 movies.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(director)
from movie
group by director
having count(distinct title) > 15
```

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
select count(director) from movie group by director having count(distinct title) > 15
```

Explanation:

The query groups all the items by directors having count of distinct titles more than 15, then counts the total no. of directors in the result.